# How to add a dictionary for spell check in Android Studio / IntelliJ Idea

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, spell-checking

I have been using Android Studio in Spanish, and it bothers me that it highlights as incorrect words which are spelt correctly.

Can I add a Spanish dictionary to Android Studio or to my IntelliJ Idea?

Comment: See the older https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949976/where-to-find-dictionaries-for-other-languages-for-intellij.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can download the Spanish (or any other language) ASCII dictionary from http://www.winedt.org/dictASCII.html and then add it to Android Studio as sebaszw said:

> 1. Go to Settings -> Spelling -> Dictionaries
> 2. Click plus symbol(+)
> 3. Select path to your dictionaries folder (inside you must have plaintext word lists with .dic extension)
> 4. Restart Android Studio

It worked for me without restarting Android Studio

Comment: Without restarting too! I tried the UNICODE file and it didn't work... With the ASCII file it works like a charm...

Comment: @RenanFranca I have the same problem, the UNICODE doesn't work and the ASCII has problems with special characters.

Comment: Does it mean that the dictionary file has to remain in that path you specified in settings when adding it?

Comment: Yes, you have to keep it in the specified folder. Otherwise it won't work. My advice is to have the dictionaries in a Dropbox/Drive/Mega/any_other folder so you can share it between different computers.

Comment: No Turkish, have to close spelling

Comment: In Android Studio 3.4.1 the path is: File > Settings > Editor > Spelling

Answer (score 46):

In **Android Studio (1.2.1.1 - 2.3.3)** you can find this here:

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Spelling -> Dictionaries, and click "+" sign next to "Custom Dictionaries Folders" grid.

**Important Note:**
You need to use **UTF-8** character coding in your "language.dic" file if you would like to use an exotic language like Hungarian, Spanish, Portuguese, etc.

1. Download from http://www.winedt.org/dict.html the UNICODE language file.
2. Unzip and open it with Windows Notepad.
3. Use "Save as" and choose **UTF-8** coding.
4. Open this file with Android Studio: File -> Settings -> Editor -> Spelling -> Dictionaries, and click "+" sign next to "Custom Dictionaries Folders" grid.
5. Restart Android Studio. Smile! You have not problems with nasty letters like "éÉíÍóÓöÖőŐúÚüÜűŰ".

Comment: thanks! it fixed the accent marks (á, é, í, ó, ú) (spanish)

Comment: Further more Android Studio will do nothing if the file is UTF-16 ! It has to be specifically UTF-8. It can be done like so "iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 myfile -o myfile_utf8" It might have to do with grep which also can't use UTF-16?  http://www.kaapstorm.com/post/how-to-grep-utf-16/

Comment: Also worth noting that if it bothers you that much, you may want to disable spell checking in comments when using a dictionary for agglutinative languages (such as Hungarian to stay at your examples). Actual code elements are likely to be simple language-wise, but comments often contain words that cannot be resolved by dictionaries - they probably don't contain words with a prefix and 5 suffixes, or similar complexity.

Comment: For the German dictionary, iconv did not work with UTF-16 as input encoding. I had to use `iso-8859-1` (AKA "Latin-1").

Comment: Thanks, this fixes German encoding. Should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 8):

1. Go to Settings -> Spelling -> Dictionaries
2. Click +
3. Select path to your dictionaries folder (inside you must have plaintext word lists with .dic extension)
4. Restart Android Studio

Answer (score 6):

Its Very Easy

Step 1: Go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> Spelling

Step 2: In Spelling -> select Tab 'Dictionaries'

Step 3: Click on '+'

Step 4: Select File that You want to put(file must be .dic extension)

Remember by default English language dictionary comes.

RESTART Android Studio is necessary.

Answer (score -3):

Go into your Settings. Under "Language and Keyboard", go to and select "Android Keyboard" -> "Input language". Choose Spanish. That should do it!

Or, on Android 4, go to Settings -> Language & Keyboard -> Touch Input (settings button) -> Personal Dictionary -> Edit personal dictionary

The following link shows how to implement a [spellchecker](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html) - you can implement this for multiple languages.

Comment: That is not what he asked. The question is about spell check on Android Studio, not in Android itself as you answer.