# Disable spell check on field names in Android Studio

Tags: android, ide, android-studio, spell-checking

I have been using Eclipse/ANT for 5 years now. Android Studio is out of beta so I am starting to get myself familiar with it. Android Studio seems to be spell checking field names. Why on earth would any IDE do that?

I still want spell check enabled, but not on any field names. I would expect spell check to only check comments or javadoc. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: This question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709263/spell-check-android-studio

Comment: take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60800611/android-studio-how-to-turn-off-typo-in-word-word/70018933#70018933

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Why on earth would any IDE do that?

I *think* because people can make typos in field names as well.

> I still want spell check enabled, but not on any field names. I would
>   expect spell check to only check comments or javadoc. How can I fix
>   this?

I'd say it's not even broken ;) Check out the preferences, you'll find that you can define the scope of spell checking. (Editor / Inspections / Spelling)

> Android Studio is out of beta

Final. Since yesterday.

Answer (score 65):

Spell check can be customized/disable via:

Android 1.1.0: File -> Settings (Project Settings [...]) -> Inspections -> Spelling -> Typo

Android 4.1.1: File -> Preferences -> Editor -> Inspections -> Proofreading -> Typo

This brings up three options that can be enabled/disabled:

1. Process code
2. Process literals
3. Process comments

Uncheck whichever boxes you would like