# Android Studio - How to turn off "typo in word 'word'?

Tags: android

When naming variables or giving String arguments Android Studio seems to have a problem with how I label things.

Is there a way to turn that off?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, open `Preferences` -> `Editor` -> `Inspections` -> `Spelling` -> toggle off `Typo` and press `OK`.

**Edit**

To make it as default not only for your project select `Profile: Default`.

[image]

Comment: That worked and under "profile" you have to select "Default" to make it persistent for the entire IDE and not just for the project.

Comment: In Android 4.0, it is in File->Settings->Editor-> Inspections -> Spelling -> toggle off Typo

Answer (score 13):

On Android Studio 4.1.x you have to open `File > Settings` and uncheck `Typo` inside `Editor > Inspections > Proofreading` (you could also find it using the search box on top of Settings screen).

[image: How to turn off Typo on Android Studio]

Answer (score 4):

In Android Studio 3.6.1 (and probably some other versions), go into File > Settings, search for "spelling", and choose the Inspections category:

[image: Android Studio Spelling Settings]

Either turn of "Typo" entirely or configure the options (lower-right corner in screenshot) to determine where you do and do not want spell-check.

The Spelling category lets you control what language dictionaries get used, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the word in "Accepted words" list:
Open `File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor/Spelling`, click `+` below "Accepted words" and add word, so you can let spell checing intact.
[image]

Edit: You can also add `@SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection")` for Java or `@Suppress("SpellCheckingInspection")` for Kotlin before a Class, Function or Sub and also keep spell checking for other parts of code.