# IntelliJ Spell checker can't handle hunspell .dic files correctly

Tags: dictionary, intellij-idea

I have some problems installing german spell checker dictionary for IntelliJ

I download the german .dic file from

http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/german-de-de-frami-dictionaries

(The Zip contains the .dic file)

[image]

After importing the dict into IntelliJ I try to use it but I see the results with suffixes. So it is 1:1 like in the

[image]

So the question is should there be a different Dictionary or is IntelliJ not capable to handle hunspell .dic file format?

Comment: See the older https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949976/where-to-find-dictionaries-for-other-languages-for-intellij.

Answer (score 1):

[Hunspell plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10275-hunspell) is available now, please install it and you will be able to add hunspell dictionaries to IntelliJ spellchecker

When hunspell plugin is installed and enabled navigate to the Settings/Preferences | Editor | Spelling, switch to the Dictionaries tab and select the dictionary folder containing hunspell dictionaires files (.dic and .aff) (till 2018.1 IDE version) or dictionary file .dic (from 2018.1 IDE version).

After this step is done hunspell dictionary will be bound to spellchecker system, it will detect and highlight typos in your text and propose corrections for them as general word list dictionaries do.

Comment: thank you for the tip. I installed the plugin. But don't know how to configure it or add dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Per IntelliJ IDEA's [Spelling Settings documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/spelling.html) and the general [Spellchecking documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/spellchecking.html), the format of files that it uses are just plain text files "containing words separated with a newline". There's no indication that I can find of being able to handle files in Hunspell format.

You can also refer to [this older Jetbrains Support forum thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206940905-Format-of-the-dic-dictionary-files-of-the-9-0-spell-checker).

You need to either convert the dictionary file you want to use into a format that just uses plain words, or find another source of a dictionary for the words you want to add.