# How to add languages [german, french, polish, czech, ...] to intellij spell checker? On Mac, Windows and Linux?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to add other languages to the IntelliJ Spell Checker?

[image: spell checker]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can download additional dictionaries here: http://www.winedt.org/dict.html

1. Download and unzip your dictionary [German, French, Spanish, ...] form [here](http://www.winedt.org/dict.html)
2. Add it to "Dictionaries" under Preferences -> Editor -> Spelling
   [image]

No Plugins are required!

Comment: There are other source of dictionaries - creted by LibreOffice project:

https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/plain/

- Germany [de_DE_frami](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/plain/de/de_DE_frami.dic), 
- Czech [cs_CZ](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/plain/cs_CZ/cs_CZ.dic)

Comment: @KubaAndrýsek, the dic files you link to will NOT work in IDEA, because they are not simple "wordlist" files - see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38264830/intellij-spell-checker-cant-handle-hunspell-dic-files-correctly for reference.