# Where can I get Polish language dictionary for IntelliJ?

Tags: dictionary, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I have had a need for Polish dictionary to PhpStorm recently. I know that [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949976/where-to-find-dictionaries-for-other-languages-for-intellij) is general topic about dictionaries for IntelliJ programs, but where i should go if i need it now, and I don't want to build it (it should be ready to use) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using various information which i found on the internet, i prepared ready to use Polish Dictionary for IntelliJ, You can find it there: https://github.com/dominik59/polish_intellij_dictionary . It covers probably all variations of the polish words, so it is valuable if you are preparing translations in Your application.

P.S. It can be use for whole JetBrains family, not only for PHPStorm.

Disclaimer: this dictionary is prepared by myself from the sources mentioned at the GitHub repository. Feel free to use it as You wish.

Comment: Remember to add a disclaimer that this is your own product. I know you mention it, but it should be highlighted. Otherwise, great work!

Comment: Thank You :) Where should I add This disclaimer ?

Comment: Just at the bottom of the answer. Disclaimer: this dictionary is  coded by myself. something like that. Great job creating a clear question and answer for this issue. I read a while back, that stack overflow encourages this, even if it seems weird to someone that you answer your own question immediately, this adds to the total value of the Q&A repository.

Comment: Thank You again :) Stack Overflow is a great tool and help me a lot in my everyday job so it is fun to make it better :)