# How to define the spelling language in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, asciidoctor

I want to create a documentation with `Asciidoc` in `Intellij`.

Is there a way to change the dictionary language in `Intellij`? For example from `english` to `german`.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949976/where-to-find-dictionaries-for-other-languages-for-intellij/16278834#16278834

Comment: @wwerner thanks - a combination of these answers did the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to combine two responses of
[Where to find dictionaries for other languages for IntelliJ ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949976/where-to-find-dictionaries-for-other-languages-for-intellij)

1. Download and unzip the dictionary from http://www.winedt.org/dict.html
2. Go to `File > Settings >` type "`dict`" in the search and click `Dictionaries >` click the green plus, go to the unzipped folder and select all `*.dic` files.

Answer (score 1):

Before you add custom dictionaries, check under:

Editor > Proofreading

as you can add certain languages via the `+`-icon.

I also needed both German and English spell-checking, my current project uses a mix of those languages and German is supported out of the box.

(This is a functionality that comes with the bundled Grazie plugin. So if you don't see that option, [you may need to add it](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12175-grazie).)

[image: Screenshot of Settigns]